# Pulseaudio mute device

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

I have an Notebook runnning Pulseaudio on an Arch Linux. This notebook is used at home in an docking station. On this one are loudspeakers connected. But sometimes I do use headphones.
How can I automatically mute the speakers and just use the headphones?

Here is the real issue: 
Both jack connectors work on the same audio device.

```
# pacmd list-sinks                                    
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 1
   ...
```

I already figured out, that when I use pulseaudio in verbose mode, booth devices are recognized accordingly to their location:

```
D: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Jack 'Headphone Jack' is now unplugged
D: [pulseaudio] device-port.c: Setting port analog-output-speaker to status unknown
...
D: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Jack 'Dock Headphone Jack' is now plugged in
...
```

Do you have any idea how I can use this information to automaticaly mute the loudspeakers?

Thanks in advance..